# How do I loop JSON response to get specific data in Javascript or GAS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script

I Have an JSON response from an external API. Problem is i only know how to log the response but not manipulate it. In this case, I need to get some information from the response and loop through the entire response to show the list of all the users. Here is my code so far. Its not a good one, but this what i could do with my minimal javascript skills.

```
 };

var response= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
var call= JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var people=call.data;
  var user= {}

    user.ID = call.data[1].id;
    user.Email = call.data[1].email;
    user.Name= call.data[1].display_name;

Logger.log(user)

}
```

Sample response:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id":00126,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test",
        "archived": false,
        "display_name": "Test Test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "termination_date": null,
        "mobile_phone": null,
        "office_phone": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "deleted": false,

    },

"data": [
    {
        "id":00126,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test",
        "archived": false,
        "display_name": "Test Test",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "termination_date": null,
        "mobile_phone": null,
        "office_phone": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "deleted": false,

    },
```

Comment: Probably simpler if you show us a sample of the response and your expected result!

Comment: It seems your code lines are mixed up, also reorder them properly would be better for us to understand what you are doing!

Comment: seems `for(i = 0; i = < people.user ;i++) {` should be changed to `for(i = 0; i = < people.length ;i++) {`

Comment: @sjahan I have edited my question. Please take a look at sample response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to iterate through data and return required information only from the object

```js
let data =  [
 {
  "id": 00126,
  "first_name": "Test",
  "last_name": "Test",
  "archived": false,
  "display_name": "Test Test",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "termination_date": null,
  "mobile_phone": null,
  "office_phone": null,
  "deleted_at": null,
  "deleted": false,

 }]

 let res = data.map(({id, email, display_name}) => ({ID: id, Email: email, Name: display_name}));
 console.log(res)
```

If ES6 is not supported

```
var res = data.map(function(userData) {
        return {ID: userData.id, Email: userData.email, Name: userData.display_name}
    });
```

Comment: Please be aware that if he/she's using GAS, the user might not be able to use ES6 tools like `let` and arrow functions.

Comment: @iamblichus added example without these two also.